# Boolean operation producing a mess

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to make an interior to a vehicle and I am having great difficulty.

I have tried the obvious, using the boolean modifier. I have tried using two different objects as a boolean and they both have had very different results, despite being pretty similar. I have also tried using the solidify modifier, the mesh gets distorted the higher the thickness.

So whats the issue with the boolean modifier? There are multiple triangle cut outs all over the interior of the model, even where there is plenty of space and topo to work with.

I will attach some screenshots below so you can see all of this in action. Thanks for your interest and if you have any ideas, please let me know in the comments.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it's a pretty complicated setup...so you should provide your blend file so we can check it out. Else we can just guess...e.g. tap fast/exact. Correct your face orientation ....etc

Comment: @Chris I don't like providing blend files so thats why I don't initially but I understand how complicated the issue is. I will edit the post and add the file.

Comment: i can understand that you don't like it...but it helps a lot for all who wants to answer. First we can test whether our solution proposal works. And second it is much easier to understand what you want. "normally" it is pretty easy to delete all objects/shader you don't need and just save a minimum version of your problem.